# inconsistencies in firefox, ie, and chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I created a custom header for a pre-made responsive theme. It looks great in chrome, but both firefox and ie aren't showing all of the menu items and are positioning a logo::after shadow in a weird spot.

I already verified that there are no errors in my code and tried implementing normalize.css, but nothing has worked to fix the problem.

This is the code I'm using:

```
.logo::after {
    content: "";
    background: transparent url("/wp-content/themes/porto/images/shadow.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    width: 247px;
    height: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 64px;
    right: 30px;
    min-height: 0px;
}
#main-menu {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you provide your html code for the custom header or provide a link to an example that replicates your problem? This will greatly assist with troubleshooting.

Comment: The code above is what I added to the existing css for the header to manipulate and position it how I wanted - instead of an actual logo, I am using several different image files so that the header responds properly. You can see my problem if you open this link in firefox or ie: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//purefucoidan.com&w=1920&h=1200&a=1

Comment: Your site does not look great in chrome. Your logo shadow positioning and menu completely break when I adjust the browser size. As for your shadow in Firefox, you can set `#header .header-main .container > .header-left {vertical-align: baseline;}` and that will get you part of the way there.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice! As far as the responsivity, I set it for the screen sizes generally found on most devices. Is this not good practice?

Comment: It depends on your project and if you are targeting specific devices. My preference is to start my css in a mobile first approach and use media queries to adjust the layout so that the content is presented in the best possible format/layout as the screen size increases. I typically do not target specific screen sizes.

Comment: Is there a reason that you do not want to use an actual image in your `.logo`?

Comment: Yes, because I was having issues positioning the logo as an image that close to the menu. It was forcing the image into a smaller box, no matter what I set the width to. By doing it this way, as a static header background, I can ensure that it stays where I want it and that the size stays proportionate.

Comment: Is there a better way to achieve the same look and feel?